# jQuery: show on click, hide on click, and loop infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. To start off, there is one row of images with a "See more" button
   underneath it.
2. When the "See more" button is clicked, a second row of images is added after the first row of images, and the
   "See more" button is replaced with a "See less" button.
3. When the "See less" button is clicked, the second row of images that was added
   in the step above gets removed, and the "See less" button gets
   removed.

**Question**: how can I make it so that this is an infinite loop, where the "See more" button would then reappear after step 3, thus allowing repetition?

Here's the jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Hides the new row to prepare for click event
        $('.images-section').children('.new-row').hide();
        //Creating variables for see more/less buttons
        var more = $('.images-button-more');
        var less = $('.images-button-less'); 
        less.hide();
        //Add new row on click of see more button
        more.on('click', function() {
            $('.images-section').children('.new-row').show(function() {
                $(this).insertAfter('.old-row').slideDown('1000');
                more.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    less.insertAfter(more).fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
        });
        //Remove new row on click of see less button
        less.on('click', function() {
            $('.new-row').slideUp('1000', function() {
                less.fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });
    });
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<section class="no-padding remove-tablet">
        <div class="container-fluid images-section">
            <div class="row no-gutter old-row">
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/ant-johns.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Ant Johns" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/white-guy.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Arnold Jr" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/enrique-double-bi.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Enrique Double Bi" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/anthony-b.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Anthony B" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/manny-most-muscular.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Manny Most Muscular" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/remi-model-tats.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Remi Model Tats" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row no-gutter new-row">
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/ant-johns.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Ant Johns" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/white-guy.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Arnold Jr" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/enrique-double-bi.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Enrique Double Bi" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/anthony-b.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Anthony B" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/manny-most-muscular.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Manny Most Muscular" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6">
                    <img src="img/remi-model-tats.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Remi Model Tats" width="317px" height="322px">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <a class="images-button-more" style="padding-bottom: 3px; border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(130,181,65); position: relative; top: 5px; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 50%">See more</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <a class="images-button-less" style="padding-bottom: 3px; border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(130,181,65); position: relative; top: 5px; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 50%">See less</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I tried putting the jQuery around an if statement, and put new variables like "isClosed, isNotClosed", and then change their values from 0 to 1 based on certain events and loop if isClosed is true, but that wasn't doing me any justice.

Comment: add the html too please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing one line in the jquery:

```
less.on('click', function() {
     $('.new-row').slideUp('1000', function() {
         less.fadeOut('slow');
         more.insertAfter(less).fadeIn('slow');//this line
     });
 });
```

Comment: This is it, thanks a lot! I knew it was something small.. couldn't wrap my head around it - only started learning jQuery a couple of days ago lol. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

one option is to load the second row of images when the page loads but hide it with `display: none` and give it an id like `id='second-row'`

then in your click event you can do the following:

```
$('#buttonId').on('click', function() {
 $('#second-row').slideToggle();
});
```

heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kqvzhoo1/

Comment: Great suggestion! That works too, thanks. Only problem is I have to rewrite some code, but works nonetheless.